# Finding all possible combinations of numbers of an array to reach a given sum

Tags: algorithm, recursion

We are provided an array of N numbers and a target value k. We need to find all possible ways to form an expression by inserting the operators (+,- and *) in such a way that the expression evaluates to the value k.
For example:

- Input: Array = {3,4,3}, k = 15
- Output: 3*4+3, 3+4*3

I couldn't develop a recursive solution to this problem. With just '+' and '-' operator, it would be easier but because of '*' operator it becomes difficult to use recursive approach as we also need to care about the precendency of operators.
Can you help me finding a suitable approach to solve this problem?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? create all possible expressions via recursion and than validate each if the result is k.

Comment: We can use any method not just recursive.

Comment: Generating all possible expressions is the right idea. Do you know how to evaluate the expression with just + and -? If so, you should post your code so far. You can use this as a subroutine to evaluate expressions with multiplication included in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me while to code this. So it's basically brute force. I recursively (backtracking) generate all possible expression with the operators given and then evaluate them. Note these are just infix expression(s).

Now this is a very slow solution. There are several optimization one can do here.

```
vector<string> allCombinations(vector<int> &arr, int k)
{
    int n = (int)arr.size();
    string operators = "+-*";
    vector<string> ans;
    // To check precedence of operators
    auto prec = [&](char op) -> int
    {
        if (op == '*' or op == '/') return 2;
        if (op == '+' or op == '-') return 1;
        return -1;
    };
    // For infix evaluation (kindof a helper function)
    auto compute = [&](int v1, char op, int v2) -> int
    {
        if (op == '+') return v1 + v2;
        if (op == '-') return v1 - v2;
        if (op == '*') return v1 * v2;
        if (op == '/') return v1 / v2;
        assert(false);
        return INT_MAX;
    };
    // Main infix evaluation function
    auto evaluate = [&](string s) -> int
    {
        int len = (int)s.size();
        // vector is being used as a STACK
        vector<int> val;
        vector<char> ops;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            char curr = s[i];
            if (curr == ' ') continue;
            if (isdigit(curr))
            {
                int v = 0;
                while (i < len and isdigit(s[i])) v = 10 * v + (s[i++] - '0');
                val.push_back(v);
                i--;
            }
            else
            {
                while (!ops.empty() and prec(curr) <= prec(ops.back()))
                {
                    int v1 = val.back();
                    val.pop_back();
                    int v2 = val.back();
                    val.pop_back();
                    char op = ops.back();
                    ops.pop_back();
                    val.push_back(compute(v2, op, v1));
                }
                ops.push_back(curr);
            }
        }
        while (!ops.empty())
        {
            int v1 = val.back();
            val.pop_back();
            int v2 = val.back();
            val.pop_back();
            char op = ops.back();
            ops.pop_back();
            val.push_back(compute(v2, op, v1));
        }
        return val.back();
    };
    // Generates all expression possible
    function<void(int, string&)> generate = [&](int i, string &s) -> void
    {
        s += to_string(arr[i]);
        if (i == n - 1)
        {
            if (evaluate(s) == k) ans.push_back(s);
            // Backtrack
            s.pop_back();
            return;
        }
        for (char &ops : operators) 
        {
            s.push_back(ops);
            generate(i + 1, s);
            // Backtrack
            s.pop_back();
        }
        // Backtrack
        s.pop_back();
    };
    string s;
    // Try all combinations
    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    do
    {
        generate(0, s);
    } while (next_permutation(arr.begin(), arr.end()));
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: OP says not allowed to use recursion

Comment: OP said `We can use any method not just recursive`, which isn't the most clear sentence, but definitely seems to allow the use of recursion or any other method. This could also be turned into an iterative solution without much difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Finding all combinations of operators is pretty simple.  If you represent each operator as a digit of a zero-prefixed number in base-3, then you can create a function that renders that base-3 number from an integer, but uses {'+','-','*'} instead of {'0','1','2'} for the digits.

```
private static final char[] CHARS = "+-*".toCharArray();
private char[] generateOperators(int i, int length){
    char[] ops=new char[length];
    for (int x=0; x<length; x++) ops[x]=CHARS[0];
    for (int x=0; x<length; x++) {
        ops[length-1-x]=CHARS[i % CHARS.length];
        i /= CHARS.length;
    }
    return ops;
}
```

You can accumulate your total left to right without backtracking.  Keep a total and a separate accumulator.  Any time your next operand is a '+' or '-', it's safe to push your accumulated value to the total.  If it's a '*', then you know the current operand is participating in the next accumulation.  In this function, I essentially treat every run of multiplied operands as a cluster, treating even single values as a cluster of one, and push that accumulated value to the total when I reach the end of a cluster.

```
public int evaluate(int[] operands, char[] operators) {
    int sum=0;
    int multiplier=1;
    for (int i=0; i<operators.length; i++) {
        int operand=operands[i];
        multiplier*=operand;
        if (operators[i]!='*') {
            sum+=multiplier;
            multiplier=operators[i]=='-' ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
    if (operators[operators.length-1]=='*') {
        multiplier*=operands[operands.length-1];
    } else {
        multiplier=(operators[operators.length-1]=='-' ? -1 : 1) * operands[operands.length-1];
    }
    sum+=multiplier;
    return sum;
}
```